# Latex on your website

Tags: mathjax, latex-misc

I am trying to build a new website from scratch. As, I would have to write mathematical and chemical expressions in the content, and I am already an avid user of physics, math and chem stack exchange websites. I would like the end product to behave similar/if possible exactly the same to the stack exchange thing.

I have no idea where to go to implement this. So, how do I implement the same type of latex editor with all the features for writing mathematical and chemical expressions in the content editor on my website.

Comment: For mathematical expressions you can use [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/). Chemical expressions aren't supported AFAIK.

Comment: This is probably off-topic

Comment: @JuriRobl What does stack exchange do for chemistry then ? Do they also mathjax for mathematical expressions ?

Comment: @lota Yes they use mathjax and I think that's it. They apparently don't use anything to typeset chemistry, just use the math stuff. If I saw it correctly.